# VPS: Taking control of hotname and /etc/resolv.conf (debian 10)

Tags: vps

Wanting to set hostname and domain name or wanting so take control of what dns server to use.

If I edit `resolv.conf` at reboot changes are reseted to what comes from dhcp

playing with `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` doesn't seem to change the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's got nothing to do with cloud settings lol

the magie manly happens in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

I commented out that line

```
send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
#       domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

Then in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg I had to adjust a couple things

```
[...]

# preserve_hostname: false
preserve_hostname: true

[...]

# - timezone

[...]

# manage_etc_hosts: true
manage_etc_hosts: false
```

I also needed to add a line in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.1.1 myName.Mydomain.foo myName
127.0.1.1 xxxxx.your-cloud.etc xxxxx
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Lost time on this... so I thought it might be nice to share the solution.